# Regex: Select All Duplicate Lines

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

Ok, I've been playing with this for a while and have gotten close, but still cannot pull it off.

I want to go from:

```
a
a
b
a
c
a
```

to (In Notepad++):

```
b
c
```

I can do:

```
a
b
c
```

Here are my best fails so far, but you get the idea:

```
^(((.+)(\r?\n))(?:(?!\1).*\s*)?)((?:(?!\2).*\s*)?(\2))+
^((.+)(\r?\n))((?:(?!\1).*\s*)?(\1))+
```

From Regexr, I just want 'test line'.
[image: Regexr]

New closest attempt:

```
^((.+)(\r?\n))(?=(.+)(\r?\n))?(\1)+
```

[image]

Comment: You should specify a programming language or a tool that you are going to utilize this regex in. This task is not a job for regular expressions. You should use a programming language. However, there is a non-optimal solution if regex engine supports infinite lookbehinds. Use Google Chrome and see it here https://regex101.com/r/zHJFSa/1

Comment: You'd probably need a variable length lookbehind which is available in .NET regex or with a little workaround in Java: [`^(.+)\r?\n(?=[\s\S]*?^\1$)|^(.+)(?:\r?\n|$)(?<=^\2\r?\n[\s\S]+)`](http://www.regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28.%2b%29%5cr%3f%5cn%28%3f%3d%5b%5cs%5cS%5d*%3f%5e%5c1%24%29%7c%5e%28.%2b%29%28%3f%3a%5cr%3f%5cn%7c%24%29%28%3f%3c%3d%5e%5c2%5cr%3f%5cn%5b%5cs%5cS%5d%2b%29&i=a%0d%0aa%0d%0ab%0d%0aa%0d%0ac%0d%0aa&r=&o=m) . Also this is not very efficient =p What regex flavor are you using?

Comment: Right now I am just using notepad++ to sort through an IP list. I have a list of all the IPs, and one of bad IPs, so I just pasted the bad ones into the document and was going to remove all matching entries... leaving the good ones only. I guess I could just write a script to do it, I'm just being lazy lol

Comment: Doesn't this work with multiline mode? `^(.+)$[\n\r?]^\1$`

Comment: Close @CAustin, but it only pulls the first two lines

Comment: So you have a listA of IP addresses, and a listB of IP address you want to remove from listA. This doesn't really sound like a regex problem to me. You can easily use an [array_diff](https://php.net/array_diff) or similar language function. Or put the lists in excel (or google sheets) and do a spreadsheet function to pop a 3rd column with the diff.

Comment: I think I misread your question. I thought you just wanted to get rid of any two duplicate lines in a row. So you're trying to flag the first duplicate lines you see, and then remove all future occurrences of that line?

Comment: Maybe not @CrayonViolent, but I'm just curious if it can be done, I'm sure other people would find it to be useful if someone figures it out

Comment: So why not just use my or revos demo and [paste your ip list there](http://www.regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28.%2b%29%5cr%3f%5cn%28%3f%3d%5b%5cs%5cS%5d*%3f%5e%5c1%24%29%7c%5e%28.%2b%29%28%3f%3a%5cr%3f%5cn%7c%24%29%28%3f%3c%3d%5e%5c2%5cr%3f%5cn%5b%5cs%5cS%5d%2b%29&i=192.168.0.1%0d%0a192.168.0.2%0d%0a192.168.0.3%0d%0a192.168.0.4%0d%0a192.168.0.1%0d%0a192.168.0.2%0d%0a192.168.0.5%0d%0a192.168.0.1%0d%0a192.168.0.3%0d%0a192.168.0.1&r=&o=m), copy back to np++ (click on "context").

Comment: @ThatCampbellKid fair enough, but I wonder if you're still overcomplicating it even in notepad++. At face value, you can just do a simple find and replace with empty string on a given IP address. Or like find `^(1.2.3.4|1.2.3.4)$` replace `(empty string)` for multiple.

Comment: I'm looking for a pure regex solution, as petty as it is lol

Comment: I could do that too @CrayonViolent, but the lists are hundreds of IPs long each lol

Comment: @ThatCampbellKid ok i'm just having trouble understanding how your regex solution will ever work though, since it doesn't actually reference your other listB you want to remove from listA. Because it sounds like you want to remove listB from listA, but you want a regex that does not reference listB at all; instead just assumes if more than one instance of an IP is found in listA, then remove all instances of it. Which may or may not be the same thing as removing all IPs found in listB.

Comment: I will also point out that regex alone cannot do what you ask. regex cannot *replace* anything. All it can do is *match* things.

Comment: It seems you want to remove all lines that have at least one duplicate in the file. It is not possible with a regex alone. You should either use the PythonScript plugin to write some script, or use a normal programming language to process the file(s).

Comment: Yes @CrayonViolent, I did not clarify that well. I pasted listB in to listA, and will then run 'replace all' on matches for the regular expression that picks up the duplicates. I'm putting a regex cheat sheet together for some less technical friends to help with a couple annoying tasks lol

Comment: @ThatCampbellKid ah ok, you actually did mention that in one of your earlier comments; I missed that. But in any case, as mentioned, there is no pure regex solution for this, because regex itself can only match things; it can't replace things. Regex is only half the equation you need.

Comment: Notepad++ can handle that part as part of it's find and replace function @CrayonViolent, so I just have to figure out the match lol

Comment: 1.) Install plugin "TextFX Character", select all, TextFX Tools > sort lines (asc) 2.) Use regex pattern [`^(.+)\R(?:\1(?:\R|$))+`](https://regex101.com/r/VwXsAh/1) to remove all lines that occure more than once.

Comment: Nice @bobblebubble! I'm going to keep looking for a few for one that doesn't need to be sorted for a little, but post it as an answer and I'll accept it if I don't find what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who haven't read through the comments, the idea is to use NP++ for filtering out an IP blacklist by dropping it into the full IP list and completely remove duplicate lines that occure anywhere.

This can be done by [use of a variable length lookbehind](http://www.regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28.%2b%29%5cr%3f%5cn%28%3f%3d%5b%5cs%5cS%5d%2A%3f%5e%5c1%24%29%7c%5e%28.%2b%29%28%3f%3a%5cr%3f%5cn%7c%24%29%28%3f%3c%3d%5e%5c2%5cr%3f%5cn%5b%5cs%5cS%5d%2b%29&i=192.168.0.1%0d%0a192.168.0.2%0d%0a192.168.0.3%0d%0a192.168.0.4%0d%0a192.168.0.1%0d%0a192.168.0.2%0d%0a192.168.0.5%0d%0a192.168.0.1%0d%0a192.168.0.3%0d%0a192.168.0.1&r=&o=m) that's not supported in Notepad++.

As a workaround and also more efficient:

1. [Sort lines by use of Plugin TextFX Character](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Sorting_Text) (select all).
2. Use a simple pattern like [`^(.+)\R(?:\1(?:\R|$))+`](https://regex101.com/r/VwXsAh/1) to remove the consecutive duplicate lines.

- `^` [line start](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)
- `(.+)\R` [capture](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) [one or more](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) characters to `\1` followed by an [`\R`](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html#whitespace) line break.
- `(?:\1(?:\R|$))+` followed by one or more (  [`\1`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html), followed by (line break or `$` end)).

Answer (score 0):

This task is not to be done with regex IMHO. This kind of task needs to be handled over to any programming languages. I am posting one of the gazillion solution, but based on shell:

```
sort file.txt | uniq -d
```

this command is going to sort through the file and display the list of duplicate values.

Comment: I know I could script it pretty easily, but I am trying to make it easier for less technical people lol, thanks though!

Comment: is regex easy compared to shell for someone that is not technical? just curious to know.

Comment: Yes lol, if I tell them to copy and paste that line into 'find and replace', I won't have to teach them how to use ssh and linux... it's a time worthy investment